# My program unexpectedly stops working

Tags: c, data-structures

I tried on codechef ide but I got a runtime error.

On Codeblocks the program asks for the first input and then just says the program has stopped working correctly.

And how to make sure I don't get any runtime errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head;

int main()
{
    head=NULL;
    int i,n,x;

    printf("\nEnter the number of nodes");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        Insert(x);
    }

    printf("\nHow many numbers?\n");
    Print();
    return 0;
}

void Insert(x)  /*To create new node in a linked list*/
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=NULL;

    struct node* temp1;
    temp1=head;

    while(temp1->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }

    temp1->next=temp;
}

void Print()  /*to print the linked list*/
{
    struct node* temp;
    temp=head;
    printf("\nThe list is");

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `head` is always `NULL`, that's wrong.

Comment: Hey, what is `void Insert(x)`????? where is the type?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code ?

Comment: I doubt it compiles and you can launch it....

Comment: `head`is initially `NULL` which is OK because the list initially contains no elements. But in `Insert` you need to test if `head` is `NULL` and act accordingly.

Comment: @LPs the code compiles in C on [ideone](http://ideone.com/fsRC1g).

Comment: @MichaelWalz `malloc` without `stdlib.h`? `Insert` and `Print` without prototype and implemented after `main`? and so on...

Comment: @LPs I know the code is ugly, but I suppose on IDEONE it's C89 (or whatever outdated standard) by default, and it compiles using those horrible implicit declarations.

Comment: @MichaelWalz AFAIK ideone saves you last configuration. It can be configure with c99 strict ;)

Comment: @LPs probably, but you are right, this code is horrible and should not compile on any modern enviironnment.

Answer (score 1):

head of the list is always NULL. 
Make this correction and done

```
 void Insert(x)
 {
        struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=x;
        temp->next=NULL;
        struct node* temp1;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp1=head;
            while(temp1->next!=NULL)
            {
                temp1=temp1->next;
            }
            temp1->next=temp;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Code in answers should be formatted correctly, please edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz tell me how to do it otherwise give a link to improve commenting like this everywhere doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yes, now it's more or less OK. Just the indentation of the main block of the Insert function isn't consitstent with the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126118/discussion-between-anjaneyulu-and-michael-walz).